# Use of overridePendingTransition resulted in classcastexception in list adapter

Tags: android, classcastexception, listadapter

I'm using a adapter to load data to a list view and I'm trying to use `overridePendingTransition` with the `intent`.

This is how I'm using it,

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

This is the `adapter.java` class

```
public class CustomListAddress extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final List<String> firstName;


    public CustomListAddress(Context c, List<String> firstName) {

        this.context = c;
        this.firstName = firstName;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return firstName.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return firstName.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.address_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblname);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(firstName.get(position));

        LinearLayout addresslist = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.addressLayout);
        addresslist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent next = new Intent(context,
                        ActivityMyAddressAdd.class);
                next.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

                 next.putExtra("firstName", firstName.get(position));

                context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
    }
}
```

When I tried it as shown in the adapter class it crashes and gives the below mentioned exception.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're passing `Application` context instead of `Activity` context to `CustomListAddress` constructor. In order to start new `Activity` you'll need to use its context.

You should do something like that:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
      CustomListAddress adapter;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...
           adapter = new CustomListAddress(this, firstName);
           ...
      }
}
```

First argument `SomeActivity.this` should do the trick

Comment: Can u how can i do that

Comment: That is your updated answer, earlier you asked to change it as getActivity() and it didn't work.

Comment: yeah, my mistake, getActivity() (which gives you Activity instance) can be called only from Fragment. I've mixed up things...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the answer by changing this line in my activity class, because need to pass the activity instance.

`adapter = new CustomListAddress(ActivityMyAddressList.this,firstName)`.